# Swift how to convert custom array to enum array

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

I have an app that uses a custom array to populate the data in a table view.  I would like to separate this data into two section in the table view.  Went through a few tutorials and found an approach that I like using enum.  The tutorial app works fine using a [[String: String]]]().

Every attempt to convert my data to [[String: String]]]() has failed and I can't convert the data that I have to the enum format.

The below code is an example of whatI am trying to do, but I have tried many other ways that also did not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

New Code, current error:

"Cannot assign value of type '[TableViewController_Main.Category]' to type 'ArraySlice<[TableViewController_Main.Category]>'"

```
enum TableSection: Int {
    case requests = 0, appointments, total
}

struct Category {
    var clientName: String
    var appType: String
    var appDateTime: String
    var status: String

    var photo: UIImage?
}

var dataView = [[TableSection: Category]]()
var dataViewLoop = [Category]()

func SetData() {

    for tableData in datas {

        guard let data1 = Category(clientName: tableData.client_name ?? "",
                                   appType: tableData.app_type ?? "",
                                   appDateTime: tableData.app_date_time ?? "",
                                   status: tableData.app_date_time ?? "",
                                   photo: tableData.photo ?? nil) as Category? else {
            fatalError("Unable to instantiate")
        }

        dataViewLoop += [data1]
    }

    dataView[.appointments] = dataViewLoop.filter({ $0.status == "confirmed" })
    dataView[.requests] = dataViewLoop.filter({ $0.status == "request" })
    // Cannot assign value of type '[TableViewController_Main.Category]' to type 'ArraySlice<[TableViewController_Main.Category]>'
```

Comment: replace `$0["status"]` with `$0.status`

Comment: Please, avoid snake_case for naming in Swift and start using camelCase. lowerCamelCase for constants/variables/functions and UpperCamelCase for types (structs, enums, ...) `date_view_loop` -> `dateViewLoop`

Comment: Consider using `map` rather than `for .. in` with an append:
    `data_view_loop = datas.map { row in
        guard let data = Category(...) else {
            fatalError("...")
        }
        return data
    }`

Comment: Also, consider adding an initializer on `Category` that takes an instance of whatever type `table_data` is to move the big block of nil coalescing out of the way.

Comment: The replace $0["status"] with $0.status worked, but now getting error:  Cannot assign value of type '[TableViewController_Main.Category]' to type '[[String : String]]?'       This error has also come up in other attempts, obviously the two data models are not compatable, but I can't seem to create two modals that are the same

Comment: any reason why data_view is not of type `[TableSection:Category]`?

Comment: Because I was trying different things, I changed it to [[Category]](), but getting error: Cannot assign value of type '[TableViewController_Main.Category]' to type 'ArraySlice<[TableViewController_Main.Category]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to correct my comment from above. Your `dataView` should be of type `[TableSection: [Category]]`.

Now some words about your `setData` function. In your loop you are using the nil coalescing operator `??` when initialising a Category. Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see how this could result in a fatalError. There is no failable initializer on the Category. Now I don't exactly know what `datas` is and where it is coming from, but if some of the properties in there are optional, I'd recommend making them optional on the Category as well.

Then try to work with `map` to transform your data. Here's an example:

```
var dataView = [TableSection: [Category]]()
var dataViewLoop = (0 ..< 10).map { i -> Category in
  let status = i % 2 == 0 ? "confirmed" : "request"

  return Category(clientName: "\(i)", appType: "\(i)", appDateTime: "nil", status: status, photo: nil)
}

dataView[.appointments] = dataViewLoop.filter({ $0.status == "confirmed" })
dataView[.requests] = dataViewLoop.filter({ $0.status == "request" })
```

Comment: This works.  It is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much!!!!  I have spent two days working on this and now I can move forward.